# MVC parse ajax to javascript excel

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, exceljs

Based on this  [article](http://www.ojdevelops.com/2013/04/using-jquery-ajax-get-with-aspnet-mvc.html) i’ve created an Excel TaskPane App

**The controller**

```
using DatabaseWeb.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DatabaseWeb.Home
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult GetEmployee()
        {
            Employee john = new Employee
            {
                Id = 1,
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Smith"
            };

            return Json(new { employee = john }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

**The model**

```
namespace DatabaseWeb.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p#getEmployee').click(function () {
        GetEmployeeUsingAjax();
    });
});

function GetEmployeeUsingAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Home/GetEmployee',
        success: function (emp) {
            $('#id').text(emp.employee.Id);
            $('#firstName').text(emp.employee.FirstName);
            $('#lastName').text(emp.employee.LastName);
        },
        error: function (emp) {
            //alert('error');
            return "error";
        }
    });
}
```

**body home.html**

```
<div id="id"></div>
<div id="firstName"></div>
<div id="lastName"></div>
<p id="getEmployee">Get Employee</p>
```

When I run the project it generate the id, firstname and lastname in my task pane. GREAT! So my next question is very simple. How can I generate the lastname in Excel (home.js)

```
function loadSampleData() {

var values = GetEmployeeUsingAjax(lastname);

Excel.run(function (ctx) {

        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

        sheet.getRange("A1").values = values;
     return ctx.sync();
        })
        .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

The above code won't work.

What is the exact syntax? The follow code show my intensions but does not work.

```
var values = GetEmployeeUsingAjax(lastname);
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a few problems with your code. The first one is that your function GetEmployeeUsingAjax does not return anything, ever. The real action is the asynch call to the success function. So you must either do your work of setting the excel values inside that function or pass another function through so it can be called from inside the success function.

Try that and if you still have problems, update the question.